# What do we call "a person who wears animal costumes"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do we call **a person who wears animal costumes** and stands outside of a restaurant for advertising purposes? They may also represent a team or an organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some might say "mascot." Another might say "in costume." And some might say "desperate."

Comment: I googled "mascot". That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you think it may be a good idea to avoid jokes like this "some might say 'desperate'" one here? It may be difficult for our audience to tell that it's a joke.

Comment: @Tanner Is there some rule against humor? Moreover, I have not seen that our audience is too shy to ask for clarification. In this case, I gave perfectly sensible answers (one particularly pertinent before the question was revised) before indulging in any humor. Pretty bleak world if we banish humor.

Answer (score 0):

**In certain online subcultures, people who wear animal costumes are (often derogatorily) called "furries"**. The people I refer to often state that they wish to become or already are an animal, and they dress up as animals in costume. This is very different from, say, mascots, who have nothing to do with this. Mascots are a symbolic representation of something (often an organisation), whereas "furries" are people who are unironically psychologically attached to the costume they wear. **The two terms are never interchangeable.**